# What is the query for top posters on Spanish.StackExchange?

Tags: support

One can query top questioners on Stackoverflow with this URL: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/160173

What, though, about the same query for different sites in the Stack Exchange "family"? Specifically, I am curious about https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the future, you might get an answer faster on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) since this question seems to be about the entire network (it's about the Data Explorer).  This is still on-topic here, so don't cross-post (unless you delete this question from here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the top right of the page you linked to, you can choose which site to query. Just copy the existing query and then go to the site you want and paste it there.

https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/327493

Comment: Ah, i missed that detail. :)

Comment: Wait, no that's my mistake.  The question isn't clear, the title says SO in Spanish, but the link is for Spanish Language.

Comment: If that were the case, then the reason would be stackoverflow in spanish is still in beta (or alpha, whatever). :)

Comment: That's a weird coincidence - I'm #4 on both StackOverflow and the Spanish StackExchange site.

Comment: wow. that's a lot of questions. :)